# Manipulating indices in and simplifying expressions

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I am self studying general relativity and at the end of 1st chapter I have found this exercise where you have to manipulate indices, but I could't solve it on my own. It goes as follows:

Let $\eta^{\mu \nu}$ be the 4-dimensional Minkowski metric. We define $$\Delta^{\mu \nu} = \eta^{\mu \nu} + u^{\mu} u^{\nu}$$ and $$\Delta^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} + \Delta^{\mu \beta} \Delta^{\nu \alpha} \right) - \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu \nu} \Delta^{\alpha \beta}$$ where $u^{\mu}$ is some timelike unit vector, i.e. $u^{\mu} u_{\mu} = −1$.

I want to write the expression $$\Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} \nabla_{(\alpha} u_{\beta )} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu}$$ in a more compact way using only $\Delta^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$.

---

This is what I have done:
Because $\nabla_{(\alpha} u_{\beta )}$ is symmetric we can write it as

$$\Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} \nabla_{(\alpha} u_{\beta )} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu} = \Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} \frac{1}{2}\left( \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta } + \nabla_{\beta} u_{\alpha} \right) - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu} = $$ $$ = \frac{1}{2} \Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta }+ \frac{1}{2}\Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} \nabla_{\beta} u_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu}$$ if we rename indeces in second term (change $\beta$ and $\alpha$) we get

$$= \frac{1}{2} \left( \Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} + \Delta^{\mu \beta} \Delta^{\nu \alpha} \right) \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu} = $$

$$= \frac{1}{2} \left( \Delta^{\mu \alpha} \Delta^{\nu \beta} + \Delta^{\mu \beta} \Delta^{\nu \alpha} \right) \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} - \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu \nu} \Delta^{\alpha \beta} \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} + \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu \nu} \Delta^{\alpha \beta} \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu}=$$
$$ = \Delta^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} + \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu \nu} \Delta^{\alpha \beta} \nabla_{\alpha} u_{\beta} - \frac{1}{3} (\nabla_{\mu} u^{\mu}) \eta^{\mu \nu}$$

Here I don't know what else can I do, I have started into expression for hours and I still can't simplify it further.
I will be glad for every ounce of help. Thanks!

Comment: Is this expression supposed to be able to be simplified, perhaps that is as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that
$$
\Delta^{\mu\alpha}\Delta^{\nu\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \Delta^{\nu\alpha}\Delta^{\mu\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)},
$$
since $\nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)}$ is symmetric in $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ and we can rename dummy indices. So one can write
$$
\Delta^{\mu\alpha}\Delta^{\nu\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\Delta^{\mu\alpha}\Delta^{\nu\beta} + \Delta^{\mu\beta}\Delta^{\nu\alpha}  \right) \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \Delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} + \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu\nu}\Delta^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)}.
$$

Now we can notice that
$$
\Delta^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \eta^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha,
$$
since $u^\beta \nabla_\alpha u_\beta = \frac{1}{2} \nabla_\alpha (u^\beta u_\beta) = 0$ as $u^2 = -1 = \mathrm{const.}$

Therefore:
$$
\Delta^{\mu\alpha}\Delta^{\nu\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \Delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} + \frac{1}{3} \Delta^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha = \Delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} + \frac{1}{3} \left( \eta^{\mu\nu} + u^\mu u^\nu \right) \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha
$$

It follows then that

$$
\Delta^{\mu\alpha}\Delta^{\nu\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} - \frac{1}{3} \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha \cdot \eta^{\mu\nu} = \Delta^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} + \frac{1}{3} u^\mu u^\nu \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha.
$$

EDIT: I haven't checked your calculation before, but it looks like the only step you are missing is $\Delta^{\alpha\beta} \nabla_{(\alpha}u_{\beta)} = \nabla_\alpha u^\alpha$.